# Timestamp with FF6 format. Need Hive UDF or RegExp

Tags: sql, date, hive, timestamp

I am just starting to learn more about HiveQL or rather SQL. 
I am a newbie and this is my first question in SOF.
Here goes the question

My source has a timestamp field coming with multiple formats. 
Be it yy-dd-mm hh.mm.ss.ssssss,mm-dd-yy hh.mm.ss.ssssss, dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss:ssssss etc any many more, But I want my hive table time colum to be in Timestamp FF6 format i.e YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS . Exactly like this after seconds dot(.) and 6 decimals after that.

So what would be the best approach? Is it better to write a UDF or Reg_exp? Please Do help me with all the possible answers with sample code. Would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **A.** If the incoming data is in a `String` column, then you may try a series of  `case when X regexp '...pattern...' then unix_timestamp(X, '...format...')`  but then you'll have to learn the syntax for Java time formats and Java regular expression patterns **B.** converting the resulting `BigInt` to `Timestamp` will give you a binary format, that you can reformat later to a `String` with any format you want with `date_format(...)` **C.** unfortunately there is no way to tell whether _02-06-2018_ means _June 2nd_ or _Feb. 6th_ without any prior information about the locale!!!

Comment: Hive Operators and User-Defined Functions (UDFs) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter for the reply. I have already written a regular expression to deal with that, again I agree with you about point C. We might have to some workaround for the same issue. Appreciate your help again.